# Need to apply a property change for items in the Angular Material 16 mat-menu (globally)

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material 16 and this question is regarding the height of each button inside of the mat-menu element.

Code Example:

```
<button mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>  
 </button>  
 <mat-menu>
    <button mat-menu-item>Menu A</button>
    <button mat-menu-item>Menu B</button>   
 </mat-menu>
```

When I Inspect this menu there is a class: `.mat-mdc-menu-item` that has a property of `min-height: 45px;`

I would like this property to be `35px;`

I would like to do this at a global level as the application is littered with these menus.  So creating a custom class to this would be tedious.

The user would like this height applied to all mat-menu buttons.

I have tried to look up `.mat-mdc-menu-item` in my project but I can't find it.  I have also tried to adjust the `.mat-menu-item` class and that did not work.

```
.mat-menu-item {
    max-height: 35px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to globally override the styles for `.mat-mdc-menu-item` in your Angular Material project, there are a few steps you should follow:

1. **Ensure you have higher specificity or use the `::ng-deep` pseudo-class**: Due to Angular's view encapsulation, the styles you write in your component might not affect child components. Using `::ng-deep` can help you bypass this. Keep in mind, though, that `::ng-deep` is technically deprecated, but as of now, it's still the most straightforward way to do this in Angular.
2. **Adjust the right property**: You mentioned you're trying to change `max-height`. However, you want to modify `min-height`, based on your description.
3. **Overriding Global Styles**: You can put this override in the global `styles.scss` (or `styles.css`) file. This way, it will apply globally.

Given these steps, here's the code you could add to your `styles.scss`:

```scss
::ng-deep .mat-mdc-menu-item {
    min-height: 35px !important;
}
```

Note the use of `!important`. This ensures that your style will take precedence. However, try to avoid using `!important` unless necessary because it can make future style changes challenging.

After you make this change, all the Material menu items should have a `min-height` of `35px`.

Remember that while this approach is straightforward, using `::ng-deep` with global styles can make your styles less modular and harder to maintain. So always comment and document why you're using such overrides.

Comment: I did not use the ::ng-deep command in your answer because, as you mentioned it is deprecated.  I did add a class .mat-mdc-menu-item { min-height: 35px !important; } - Thank you!